# Change default screen resolution on Windows Server 2012R2 Azure VM

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, screen-resolution

When I connect to my Windows Server 2012R2 Azure VM via RDP, I have resolution 1600x900, which corresponds to my client PC resolution.
However, when I run selenium UI tests on this machine with VSO agent, they are failing because screen resolution for agent session is 1024x768.
In Device manager I can see that display adapter is Microsoft Hyper-V Video.
When I access Screen Resolution section when connected via RDP, I can see only my resolution selected and grayed out and also message "The display settings can't be changed from a remote session".
Is it possible to change default screen resolution for Windows Server 2012R2 running on Azure VM? 
I tried adding DefaultSettings.XResolution and DefaultSettings.YResolution values to registry but it didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I could find, there is no way to set the default resolution higher than 1024 x 768. So we added a few blocks in the build definition to setup a RDP connection to do the trick. [See this post/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45829787/increase-the-screen-resolution-on-test-agent/47907240#47907240)